# how to change this code that use xrange to run in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm reading the High-Performance Python book from O'Reilly collection, in the page number 11 I found this code that works for python 2, the point here is to make one instruction that performs(by vectorizing) several at the same time

```
import math 
def check_prime(number):
    sqrt_number = math.sqrt(number)
    number_float = float(number)
    numbers = range(2, int(sqrt_number)+1)
    for i in xrange(0, len(numbers), 5):
          # the following line is not valid Python code
          result = (number_float / numbers[i:(i+5)]).is_integer()
          if any(result):
                 return False
    return True
```

but I get this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'
```

I've tried to change it to work on python 3 here is my try:

```
import math

def check_prime(number):
    sqrt_number = math.sqrt(number)
    number_float = float(number)
    numbers = list(range(2, int(sqrt_number)+1))

    for i in range(0, len(numbers), 5):
        # the following line is not valid Python code
        result = (number_float / numbers[i:(i+5)]).is_integer()
        if any(result):
            return False
    return True
```

I changed the `xrange` for `range` and the `range(2, int(sqrt_number)+1)` for `list(range(2, int(sqrt_number)+1))` but i did not have succeed in this. I suppose there is a special operator for sets or something like that but have no idea. if any of you people can help me I'll be so grateful whit you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the book and that line is not supposed to actually work as is; you cannot divide by a list in Python. The author uses that code as an example of what vectorization **would** look like. The `# the following line is not valid Python code` comment is in the original to indicate that.

The closest in term of functionality and semantics would probably be this code:

```py
import math

def check_prime(number):
    sqrt_number = math.sqrt(number)
    number_float = float(number)
    numbers = list(range(2, int(sqrt_number)+1))

    for i in range(0, len(numbers), 5):
        # the following line is now valid Python code, but not vectorized
        result = [(number_float / n).is_integer for n in numbers[i:(i+5)]]
        if any(result):
            return False
    return True
```

Note that the processing for result in this version is not done in parallel, so it's probably not what the author wanted to demonstrate. As far as I know, vectorization isn't natively available in Python, you would have to use `numpy` to do it. [This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-vectorization-5b882eeef658) should be useful if you want to try it.

Comment: thanks srry for the non-reading-bias i will be more careful next

Comment: Don't worry too much, it happens. And we're biased to expect code in a programming book to be valid

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import math

def check_prime(number):
    sqrt_number = math.sqrt(number)
    number_float = float(number)
    numbers = list(range(2, int(sqrt_number)+1))

    for i in range(0, len(numbers), 5):
        result = [number_float % num == 0 for num in numbers[i:(i+5)]]
        if any(result):
            return False
    return True
```